# How to find constructor values being passed to a contract

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan

I'd like to find out which values were passed in when someone deployed a CrowdSale token. Is there a way to find out.

Here is Lunyr [Crowdsale contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xfa05A73FfE78ef8f1a739473e462c54bae6567D9#readContract)

How would I find out which values they passed in when they deployed a contract.

Comment: From the same page it says it was created at https://etherscan.io/tx/0x06e552bd2f55cb6097bbcac2b3ba5b3ec9ee8b1edb1820aa369a0418e493836b. In the input data is the contract, the constructor params are at the end, each is 32 bytes, lunyrMultisig address 0x83c54a.., upfradeMaster same address, startBlock 0x348078, endBlock 0x372378

Comment: It's current values of the contract, I'd like to know when the contract was first created with which constructor parameters. Your link also doesn't show that information

Comment: It is inside the "Input Data" text box. If you scroll to the end of the textbox there are your three parameters in hexadecimal and padded to 32 bytes.

Comment: how do I convert input data to human readable ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not aware of a package that can parse "Input Data". I've used github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi to parse contracts calls, but not for contract creation. The full spec should be in the Ethereum Yellow Paper.

Answer (score 2):

## Automatic decoding with ethscan

You can get the ABI-encoded constructor arguments for a contract from something like etherscan in the `Contract` tab in the `code` section at the bottom titled `Constructor arguments` at the bottom of that page.

[image: Etherscan image instructing where to click]
[image: Constructor arguments at the bottom of the etherscan page]

---

## No automatic decoding?

If your blockchain explorer doesn't automatically decode the arguments (like bscscan), you can decode them using a library like [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/#AbiCoder-decode) to decode the constructor arguments.

For example:
If I wanted to decode [this contract](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x4B1B704936d1766134A24F5913730650B2326ff9#code):

**1.** I would get the arguments as a single string from the bottom of the page: `000000000000000000000000a21e605b42e9b71fa2be59587984c7fb754c6226000000000000000000000000ddec1b25461fc2b216b7e4ab2dbe4ab688c5e023000000000000000000000000f26f0e936a36b4a475cb19f150292adb53e696e6`
[image: Constructor arguments at the bottom of bscscan]
***1.1.** If your explorer doesn't have the constructor arguments listed, they are the final characters at the bottom, each argument being a 64-character string* [image: Constructor arguments]

**2.** After you have the constructor arguments, you simply need to know what type they were passed in as to decode them. In my case they are the the first array of objects. [image: Array of values from ABI]

**3.** Now I can just use [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/#AbiCoder-decode) (or similar library) to decode them like so:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.umd.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script>
    const data = "0x000000000000000000000000a21e605b42e9b71fa2be59587984c7fb754c6226000000000000000000000000ddec1b25461fc2b216b7e4ab2dbe4ab688c5e023000000000000000000000000f26f0e936a36b4a475cb19f150292adb53e696e6";
    // Array of values below are the `internalTypes` from the ABI
    console.log(ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(["address", "address", "address"], data));
</script>
```

Comment: I should add as a side note that addresses can be decoded without a library. Addresses are simply the first 40 characters, so you just need to get rid of the leading 24 0s `000000000000000000000000a21e605b42e9b71fa2be59587984c7fb754c6226` becomes `a21e605b42e9b71fa2be59587984c7fb754c6226`